# How to update stock table quantity on the basis of expiry date?

Tags: c#, mysql, fifo, inventory-management

Hello everyone i have a table of inventory stock with columns as following

```
Item_ID  | Expiry_Date | Quantity | Rate
 cB0001  | 01-18-2021  |     5    | 150
 cB0001  | 12-08-2020  |     3    | 145
 cB0001  | 02-15-2021  |     25   | 155
```

Note : Rate is not an issue I just want to update the Stock Table Quantity on the basis on expiry date and available qty.

Now i want to sale inventory to customers of item cB0001 qty : 10  from the stock that expire first. Now the problem is that sale quantity is 10 and I want to minus the quantity 5 of expiry date 01-18-2021 and 3 From expiry date 12-08-2020 and 2 from 02-15-2021. Basically i want to implement FIFO logic using one query. I want to update the stock table quantity using this

```
update stock set quantity = quantity - '10' where item_id = 'cB0001' and expiry_Date < Now()
```

But this not giving accurate result. How to fix this problem? you have any idea?

I hope you understand my question

Comment: Expiry_Date is not in MySQL date formate.

Comment: @SatishGupta Yes I know mysql format is yyyy-MM-dd. format is not a problem. If you have a solution to my problem it will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Your update SQL doesn't make sense in relation to the columns you show.  Why are you deducting 10 from quantity of cb0001 if there is only 5 - currently you'd set that row to -5.

Comment: run select '06-18-2021' < Now() on your MySQL this will return true but in select '2021-06-18' < Now() will return false

Comment: @SatishGupta Mysql version is 5.3

Comment: @SatishGupta 
Actually item cb0001 quantity is 33 with different expiry dates I want to deduct sale quantity assume 10 from stock table which expire first Like 5 from 01-18-2021 3 From 12-08-2020 and 2 From 02-15-2021. I need a update query which update all rows of stock with item_id cb0001 by deducting sale quantity. Query automatically deduct the quantity on the base of expiry date. I hope you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you intend to do this in a trigger. So the 'trick' is to work out when the sale is fulfilled (working out IF it can be fulfilled is another issue). To do this allocate a value of 0 to rows where the cumulative quantity is less than the sale, 1 to the row where the sale can finally be fullfilled and 2 after that. I have assumed there is a unique row identifier to cope with multiple inventory entries for the same date - in my case inventory.id

```
drop table if exists inventory,sales;
create table inventory
(id int auto_increment primary key,Item_ID varchar(20),  Expiry_Date date,  Quantity int, Rate int);

create table sales (item_id varchar(20), quantity int);

insert into inventory values
( null,'cB0001'  , str_to_date('01-18-2021','%m-%d-%Y'),     5    , 150),
( null,'cB0001'  , str_to_date('12-08-2020','%m-%d-%Y'),     3    , 145),
( null,'cB0001'  , str_to_date('02-15-2021','%m-%d-%Y'),     25   , 155),
( null,'cB0001'  , str_to_date('02-15-2021','%m-%d-%Y'),     10   , 155),
( null,'cB0001'  , str_to_date('02-15-2021','%m-%d-%Y'),     10   , 155),
( null,'cB0001'  , str_to_date('02-15-2021','%m-%d-%Y'),     10   , 155),
( null,'cB0002'  , str_to_date('02-15-2021','%m-%d-%Y'),     30   , 155);

drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t after insert on sales
for each row 
begin
update  inventory  left join
(select s.*,
         if(fst = 0, @runqty:=@runqty+quantity,@runqty:=@runqty) qty
from
(
select *,
         @t:=@t+quantity cumqty,
         if(@t>=@sale,if(@p>=1,2,@p:=1),@p:=0) fst
from inventory
cross join (select @t:=0,@p:=0,@sale:=new.quantity) t
where quantity > 0 and item_id = new.item_id
order by item_id,expiry_date
) s
cross join (select @runqty:=0) r
where fst in (0,1)
) a
on a.id = inventory.id 
set inventory.quantity = case when fst = 0 then 0 
                                      when fst = 1 then inventory.quantity - (new.quantity - a.qty)
                                 else inventory.quantity
                                 end;

end $$

delimiter ;


MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into sales values('cb0001',10);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.095 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from inventory order by item_id,expiry_date;
+----+---------+-------------+----------+------+
| id | Item_ID | Expiry_Date | Quantity | Rate |
+----+---------+-------------+----------+------+
|  2 | cB0001  | 2020-12-08  |        0 |  145 |
|  1 | cB0001  | 2021-01-18  |        0 |  150 |
|  3 | cB0001  | 2021-02-15  |       23 |  155 |
|  4 | cB0001  | 2021-02-15  |       10 |  155 |
|  5 | cB0001  | 2021-02-15  |       10 |  155 |
|  6 | cB0001  | 2021-02-15  |       10 |  155 |
|  7 | cB0002  | 2021-02-15  |       30 |  155 |
+----+---------+-------------+----------+------+
7 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into sales values('cb0001',25);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.111 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from inventory order by item_id,expiry_date;
+----+---------+-------------+----------+------+
| id | Item_ID | Expiry_Date | Quantity | Rate |
+----+---------+-------------+----------+------+
|  2 | cB0001  | 2020-12-08  |        0 |  145 |
|  1 | cB0001  | 2021-01-18  |        0 |  150 |
|  3 | cB0001  | 2021-02-15  |        0 |  155 |
|  4 | cB0001  | 2021-02-15  |        8 |  155 |
|  5 | cB0001  | 2021-02-15  |       10 |  155 |
|  6 | cB0001  | 2021-02-15  |       10 |  155 |
|  7 | cB0002  | 2021-02-15  |       30 |  155 |
+----+---------+-------------+----------+------+
7 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will check it and get back soon

Comment: Hi Can we do this stuff without using triggers? If yes then how can we do this

Comment: It return the Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Quantity' in 'field list'

Comment: Its work for your table structure but not mine it give me error 'quantity' is unknown column in field list while inserting into sale and sale already has column quantity. where I miss something? If I drop the trigger row is inserting successfully into sale but after trigger creating it does not work